# sympy generates exception on integrate(log(abs(x)),x)

Tags: python, sympy

`integrate(log(abs(x)),x)` gives exception. But `integrate(log(x),x)` does not. Why?

```
>python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x=symbols('x')
>>> integrate(log(x),x)
x*log(x) - x
>>> integrate(log(abs(x)),x)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1295, in integrate
    risch=risch, manual=manual)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 486, in doit
    conds=conds)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 926, in _eval_integral
    for arg in result.args
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 926, in <listcomp>
    for arg in result.args
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 1554, in doit
    for term in self.args]
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 1554, in <listcomp>
    for term in self.args]
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 397, in doit
    function = function.doit(**hints)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 1554, in doit
    for term in self.args]
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 1554, in <listcomp>
    for term in self.args]
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 1315, in doit
    return self.func(expr, *self.variables, **hints)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 1208, in __new__
    expr = Expr.__new__(cls, expr, *unhandled_variables, **assumptions)
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'manual'
```

Here is the result from Maple

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If sympy can't integrate it, should it not return the input unevaluated instead?

Comment: Maybe you should report a bug. It gives the same results when using a real `x`.

Answer (score 1):

In SymPy 1.1, the code given in the question throws an error. But the following does not:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x', real=True)
print(integrate(log(x),x))
print(integrate(log(abs(x)),x))
```

Output:

```
x*log(x) - x
Integral(log(Abs(x)), x)
```

While throwing an unhandled exception in the middle of a computation is not intended behavior (i.e., it is a bug), it is nonetheless worth noting that declaring real variables as real (and positive as positive, etc) can save some trouble.

See the list of [assumption attributes](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.assumptions).

Comment: Great to see it works on sympy 1.1, I tried exactly the same on (ancient) 0.7.6 and there it failed.